# dynamic formatted field java

Tags: java, linux, swing, jformattedtextfield

I use a format mask (# # #. # #) to fill in the values ​​nautical miles. but I want the value in front of the coma can be one, could be two or three digits. friends may be able to give me a solution. thank you

Comment: _What_ comma? I don't see one.

Comment: Could you please give us some excepted sample inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

From tha javadocs for [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), when using `#`, zeros in front or behind the decimal point are not shown, using `0` always shows zeros:

with `###.###`

- 21,345 formats as 21,345
- 21,3 formats as 21,3

with `000.000`

- 21,345 formats as 021,345
- 21,3 formats as 021,300